# Change Lifetime Sales Statistics in backend

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, backend, sales

I'm in a serious need of help as I need to alter the **lifetime sales** figure on my store's backend. It's for taxation purpose and I'm clueless about how I can reduce the digits mentioned in the stats. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

To alter the lifetime sales, you can do this :

```
<?php

/**** Database Connection ****/
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "your_db_user";
$password = "Your_Db_Pass";
$dbname = "your_db_name";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true));
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully<br/>";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    exit;
}
/**** End Database Connection ****/


$getQuery = "SELECT qty_ordered, product_id FROM sales_flat_order_item";

$result = $conn->query($getQuery);

foreach ($result as $row) {
    // To reduce by 10%, for example
    $newQty = ceil($row['qty_ordered'] * .90);
    echo "ID = " . $row['product_id'] . " Original Qty = " . $row['qty_ordered'] . "<br/>";
    echo "New Qty = $newQty<br/>";
    $setQuery = "UPDATE sales_flat_order_item SET qty_ordered = $newQty WHERE product_id = " . $row['product_id'];
    $conn->exec($setQuery);
}
```

Put that into a script in your magento root and navigate to it in your browser. After you run, in the Magento backend go to Reports->Refresh Statistics and reindex all reports. I'm not sure how much you want to reduce the figures by, but if you manipulate this line `$newQty = ceil($row['qty_ordered'] * .90);` you should be able to get the result you are looking for.